# Eclipse manage file suffix list

Tags: eclipse

I decided to move some of my jsp files into separate files with special filetype (named ***.part**). Now I imported that files to be handled like jsp's to color them and make the coding more convenient.
I can find the new extension in `"preferences/web/jsp/Add this suffix"`. Some comparable, registered file types can be found under e.g. `pref./web/html` or `pref./web/css`.

But how can I delete these types again? How to manage these files?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my above-mentioned question:

In Eclipse: Preferences->General->Content-Types->Text->[Remove/Add file here]